# Possible isometry groups of open manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry-groups

Consider a non-compact manifold $M$.

Does there always exist a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that the isometry group is non-compact?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $M$ be the triply punctured 2-sphere (i.e. $M=S^2-\{p_1, p_2, p_3\})$); one can also take any noncompact connected surface of finite topological type as long as $\chi(M)<0$ but the proof is a bit more involved.

Suppose that $g$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$. To simplify matters, I consider only orientation-preserving isometries.

Then $\mathrm{Isom}(M,g)< \mathrm{Conf}(M,g)$. I claim that $\mathrm{Conf}(M,g)$, the group of conformal automorphisms of $(M,g)$, is finite. The mapping class group of $M$ (the group of self-diffeomorphisms of $M$ modulo isotopy) is finite (isomorphic to the dihedral group of order $6$); hence, it suffices to prove that if $f: (M,g)\to (M,g)$ is a conformal automorphism isotopic to the identity then $f=\mathrm{id}$. This is quite standard (most likely, you will find it in Farb-Margalit's book on the mapping class group).

Note that $f$ is isotopic to the identity if and only if it induces an inner automorphism of $\pi_1(M)$.

By the uniformization theorem, $(M,g)$ is conformal to the quotient of the hyperbolic plane $H^2$ by a discrete group of isometries $\Gamma$ (isomorphic to $F_2$, the free group on two generators). The map $f$ then lifts to an isometry $F$ of $H^2$ (a linear-fractional transformation in, say, the Poincare disk model of $H^2$) which commutes with every element of $\Gamma$ (since $f$ induces an inner automorphism of $\pi_1(M)\cong \Gamma$). In particular, $F$ acts on the boundary circle $S^1$ of $H^2$ fixing fixed points of all elements of $\Gamma$. Since $\Gamma$ is free of rank 2, the set of fixed points of its nontrivial elements is infinite. Hence, $F$ fixes at least three points of $S^1$.    Hence (being a linear-fractional transformation), $F=\mathrm{id}$; thus, $f=\mathrm{id}$.

To conclude, every Riemannian metric on $M$ has finite group of isometries.

Edit: I can prove the same claim for each noncompact complete hyperbolic $n$-manifold of finite volume, but a proof is more difficult.

In general, the question can be reformulated in purely topological terms: Which smooth noncompact connected manifolds admit smooth proper actions of noncompact Lie groups? I suspect, this was studied in 1960s...

Comment: Counterexample: Represent $M$ as the open disk in $\mathbb R^2$ with two smaller closed disks omitted, and consider the vector field $\partial_x$ restricted to $M$. Then apply the construction of my answer. I think that your answer is correct, if you also ask for a complete Riemannian metric on $M$.

Comment: @PeterMichor: I am not using completeness of the metric $g$: Uniformization theorem does not require it. As for your example of a vector field, it will be "incomplete" and will not define an $R$-action. I think you will have this problem in general. The proof that I wrote is quite standard in hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: Aha. Now I am confused. I think that my construction goes through in this case. I gave an argument for making the vector field complete by multiplying it with a function (for example $1/\|X\|^2_{g}$ with respect to a complete auxiliary metric $g$.

Comment: @PeterMichor: Yes, you can make the vector field complete by rescaling, but it will not define an $R$-action. Just think if the horizontal line which crosses the larger disk and is tangent to the boundary of a smaller disk. Along this line you will loose continuity of the $R$-action that you are trying to define: This line has to be the union of two flow-lines but it appears as a limit of a sequence of complete flow-lines.

Comment: As the flow lines near the boundary of the inner disk, they slow down. This tangent to the inner disk splits into two flow lines, which cannot be separated in the orbit space which is therefore not Hausdorff. One does not loose continuity of the $R$-action, since the tangent point is at infinity. Obviously every complete vector field gives an $R$-action.  Very interesting discussion.

Comment: A self-homeomorphism does not induce at all an automorphism of the $\pi_1$. Indeed it induces an element of the Out, which is trivial iff your self-homeomorphism is isotopic to identity.

Comment: Slightly reformulated, one can proceed without the initial reductions: the group of isometries preserves (/antipreserves) the given conformal structure. Then, by uniformization, it acts on a complete hyperbolic manifold of the same topological type, (anti)preserving the conformal structure. Since $\chi<0$, it acts on the latter by isometries. Then one concludes, as you do, checking that the isometry group of the latter is finite (whenever the given hyperbolic surface has finite type).

Comment: @Misha: The group is order 12, not 6: there's a reflection involution fixing the punctures.

Comment: @Ian Agol: I know: In the answer I said that I am restricting to orientation preserving maps to simplify the discussion.

Comment: @Misha ah, I see that now, I guess I was going off of your comment above on the original question.

Comment: @Misha what is $\chi(M)$ for non compact $M$?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: $\chi$ is the alternating sum of Betti numbers assuming that they are all finite, like in our case. Otherwise, $\chi$ is undefined.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is sometimes yes:

If $M$ admits a complete vector field $X$, such that
its flow
$\operatorname{Fl}^X: \mathbb R\times M \to M$ is a proper action, then  there exists a Riemannian metric which is invariant under the flow, by the following

Theorem. If M is a proper G-manifold, then there is a G-invariant Riemann metric on M.

which is due to Palais if I remember correctly. A proof of this theorem can be found in 6.30 of [Topics in Differential Geometry. AMS, 2008](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/tgbook.pdf).

Finally, the isometry group then contains a non-compact 1-parameter group (this is not enough: it might be dense) which moves each point towards infinity for $t\to\infty$. So the isometry group cannot be compact (in the compact-open topology).

The existence of such a vector field is a nontrivial condition, since then $M$ is the total space of real line bundle, as pointed out by Misha Kapovich. This is actually proved in 29.21 of [1](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/tgbook.pdf).

See his answer for an example where the answer is no.

## ADDED:

The converse is also true: If the (connected component of the) isometry group is not compact, it contains a closed 1-parameter group whose generating vector field then has proper flow.

Comment: If I look at the vector field $y\partial_x - x\partial_y$ then it should be complete on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, where it has no zeros. But I think the flow is not proper, as for any point $x$ we have $\varphi_X^{2\pi n}(x)=x$.  Is that correct?

Comment: True, one needs a vectorfield without periodic orbit.

Comment: If you have a proper $R$-action then $M$ is diffeomorphic to the total space of an $R$-bundle; of course, many noncompact manifolds do not admit such.

Comment: But the $\mathbb R$-bundle is over a non-Hausdorff space, in general. In particular, in the 3 punctured sphere: Where 1 orbit becomes two, the two cannot be separated. See www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/vect-mf.pdf

Comment: Proper actions have Hausdorff quotient spaces. What you explained nicely in your linked note is that given an incomplete vector field on a manifold, you can extend it to a complete vector field on a (potentially) non-Hausdorff manifold. What happens in the 3-holed sphere example is that the quotient is obviously non-Hausdorff and, hence, you cannot get a proper $R$-action (even though, individual trajectories are proper, of course). What you have here is a variation on the standard example of a non-proper $R$-action on the punctured affine plane, given by $(t, (x,y))\mapsto (e^tx, e^{-t}y)$.

Comment: Okay, this convinces me. I shall adapt my answer.