# Non-existence of a parametrically compatible metric to a complete geodesible vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Inspired by [this answer to the question entitled "Possible isometry groups of open manifolds"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336073/possible-isometry-groups-of-open-manifolds/336092#336092)  we ask the following question:

> Is there a  complete vector field  $X$ on  $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ whose foliation is  a  geodesible  foliation but there is  no a Riemannian metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{p,q\}$ such that all trajectories of  $X$ are length parametrized geodesics? ($|X|_g=1$)